# Stimulate Click on a Button . issues

Tags: javascript

so there is a game that i'm trying to create a script for it to skip some popup overlays
the issue is when i stimulate a click on start button it returns undefined

```
document.getElementById("play-button").click()
```

but when use code like this

```
    var click_event = new CustomEvent('click');
    var btn_element = document.getElementById("play-button");
    btn_element.dispatchEvent(click_event)
    console.log('Clicked it :(')
```

the game actually start but the issue is with the main hud that contain the play button
it wont accept the click by js and wont disappear unless i actually press the button with the mouse :(

Comment: have you tried `new Event('click', {cancelable: true});` ? I think CustomEvents are different than just Events

Comment: is same result doesn't count as actual click

Comment: whats the game I would like to try it

Comment: is called vanis.io what ever i try to click gives undefined the only one that actually accepted is the dispatch event it start but the hud still on wont go :\